# Special characters in xml encoding using dom and java?

Tags: java, xml

I have some code to transform an Excel file to an XML one but when the cell's text contains some special characters, I'm unable to handle then correctly. For example:
a cell contains texts like

```
(Destinataire de flux entrants ou Origine de flux sortants) **==>** trallla
```

when tranforming it into xml, I get

```
(Destinataire de flux entrants ou Origine de flux sortants) **==&gt** trallla
```

How can I get around of this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You do not want '>' to be part of a value in a xml tag as it's a character that denotes the end of a tag. If it's substituted to &gt automatically than be happy it is. Your XML would become unusable otherwise.
Typically any parsing of the XML afterwards will know how to handle the &gt part and re-substitute it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp). If this can help you solve your problem.

Comment: CDATA is the recommended (and intended) mechanism for potentially "unsafe" character data.

Comment: That's true but he only parses the XML which has been generated by Excel. Therefore CDATA isn't a solution as he can not change the creation progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems reading esacaped HTML characters you can use [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library which includes the method [StringEscapeUtils.html.unescapeHtml(..)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29).

The unescaped String is the input you want.